Multiple commits are showing while merging hotfix in develop branch - Git
Current Git structure

I created a ticket branch from the develop branch and made some changes. After the release, I merged my ticket branch with both the main and develop branches. Now, I need to provide a hotfix.
I created a new branch from the main branch, made the necessary changes in the hotfix branch, and then merged it back into the main branch successfully. However, when merging the hotfix branch with the develop branch, I encountered an issue where two commit IDs appeared in one commit: one with changes from the hotfix and the other with changes from the last release commit.
Here is the rephrased version:

Is the process I followed to provide the hotfix correct?
Is there a standard method for providing a hotfix?
Is it normal to get two commits when merging the hotfix into the develop branch?




Is the process I followed to provide the hotfix correct?


Yes, you did follow the right steps, as according to the Gitflow approach, hotfix branches are the only ones that should branch directly from the main line of development and merged into both main and develop.


Is there a standard method for providing a hotfix?


Yes, the standard approach is Gitflow, which is also the one you followed, and you can read more about it in this Atlassian guide. Here is also an extract from the article on how to deal with hotfix.
"Maintenance or “hotfix” branches are used to quickly patch production releases. Hotfix branches are a lot like release branches and feature branches except they're based on main instead of develop. This is the only branch that should fork directly off of main. As soon as the fix is complete, it should be merged into both main and develop."


Is it normal to get two commits when merging the hotfix into the develop branch?


Yes, it is. When your application is ready to be shipped, the release branch has come to an end, and needs to be merged into both main and develop. Although these two merges bring the same set of commits, they create two different merge commits with two different SHA1s (let's call them X and Y). When you've created the hotfix branch off of main, and then made a commit on this branch (let's call it Z), the hotfix commit Z has as its parent the merge commit X, which is not included in develop's history. Therefore, when you're merging hotfix into develop, you're not just bringing Z into its history, but also X. This is why you're seeing two commits.
If we apply what we just said to your scheme, the first purple commit is X, the red commit is Z, and the first green commit is Y. Therefore, when merging hotfix into develop you're integrating "the first purple commit" (X) and "the only red commit" (Z).
